# Bicycle tire friction on wet roads

Tags: friction

Recently, I got caught in the rain while riding my road bike. Being wet and miserable made me ponder the following:

The general wisdom is that wet roads are more slippery, thus the rider should be more careful with braking and cornering.
If there is less friction between the road and the tire, it should take less energy to propel the bike forward or increased speed with the same power.

At the same time, breaking the surface tension and viscosity of water (as in riding through puddles) should require additional power.

How does the physics of this works out? Am I correct that wet roads are faster?

I am looking for the back of a napkin calculation.

Comment: "*If there is less friction between the road and the tire, it should take less energy to propel the bike forward*" I don't understand this part or why you think this. Can you explain this more?

Comment: You need the energy to add it to the kinetic energy and to compensate for drag.

Comment: Another factor that I'm surprised you didn't mention is the acceleration of water picked up by the tire and flung off seeming all in the direction of the rider.

Comment: friction between road and tyre does no work. Wet conditions generate other resistive forces, including displacing water on the road and accelerating rain when you hit it.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I am interpreting Newton's laws. If there is less resistance due to reduced friction, less energy is needed to keep the system going.

Comment: @EriksKlotins, resistance/energy loss isn't due to friction.  It's due to other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The general wisdom is that wet roads are more slippery, thus the rider
> should be more careful with braking and cornering.

Correct, because we rely on static friction to prevent skidding and sliding on the road.

> If there is less friction between the road and the tire, it should
> take less energy to propel the bike forward or increased speed with
> the same power.

This doesn't make sense. Static friction is your friend. It prevents relative motion between the tire and road (prevents spinning of the wheel) thus enabling you to accelerate your bike. You know this because if you attempt to accelerate the bike (or a car) on a slippery surface the wheel(s) will simply spin in place and you will go nowhere.

> At the same time, breaking the surface tension and viscosity of water
> (as in riding through puddles) should require additional power.

Sure, but that has less to do with friction of the water against the tire and  more to do with with the extra work you have to do to plow through the water (push it out of the way).

> Am I correct that wet roads are faster?

Quite the contrary. When riding in wet weather conditions you should go considerably slower than normal due to the increased risk of uncontrolled sliding and skidding.

> Regarding your second point: The resistance comes from static friction
> or kinetic friction?

The resistance to the tire slipping comes from static friction. Think of static friction as what gives you traction when you accelerate. It also slows you down when your are braking while the wheels are rolling (not skidding)

Once sliding or skidding occurs, the resistance to sliding or skidding is kinetic friction. For example, if you brake hard so that the wheel stops turning and you skid then your stopping distance is determined by kinetic friction. The lower the kinetic friction, the farther you will skid before stopping.

> And, which one is affected by the wetness of the surfaces?

Both are affected by the wetness of the surface, that is, both the coefficients of static and kinetic friction are lower. But the maximum possible static friction force must first be exceeded before the kinetic friction force takes over. The kinetic friction force is generally lower than the static friction force.

> The last point: My question was: Does the wetness of tire and the road
> somehow reduces friction to the extent that it gets easier to pedal to
> maintain a constant speed (compared to a dry road)? –

Moving at constant speed means the net force acting on the bicycle is zero. For the net force to be zero, generally you need to apply a torque (force) to your bike that equals the air resistance and rolling resistance forces.

As long as the torque you apply by pedaling does not result in you exceeding the maximum static friction force $u_{s}mg$ between the tire and the road, it doesn't matter if the road is wet or dry. Problem is, if it is wet, $u_{s}$ is lower than for a dry surface so you will exceed the maximum static friction force sooner and slip if the road is wet instead of dry.

So the short answer to your question is the greater the constant speed you want to maintain, the dryer the road has to be. It's not a matter of having to pedal harder, it's that *you won't be able to pedal harder* to maintain a constant speed on a wet surface because you will lose traction sooner than on a dry surface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Regarding your second point: The resistance comes from static friction or kinetic friction? And, which one is affected by the wetness of the surfaces? The last point: My question was: Does the wetness of tire and the road somehow reduces friction to the extent that it gets easier to pedal to maintain a constant speed (compared to a dry road)?

Comment: @EriksKlotins I have updated my answer to respond to your follow up questions. Hope it helps.